# firebase table list all users

Tags: android, firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database

How would be the structure of a database that  is like a game? where users can play and I store the points time etc, and there's a differents levels and then I want to query users by difficulty, my guess is something like

```
users
   -- id
      --- name
      --- ....
   -- id
      --- name
      --- ....
```

Then the difficulty table

```
diff
  -- id
    -- 2
  -- id
    -- 3
```

And then I want like a table to store like a ranking the user with the level and points, how would be the database structure?

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase data structure for ranking will be like this:

```
Ranking
  -- level 1
       -- 1  // top list for level 1
           -- name -> username1 (value)// user details, point and name, can be store more details.
           -- point -> 300
       -- 2        
           -- name -> username2
           -- point -> 260
       ......

  -- level 2
       -- 1 // 1st user
           -- name -> username1
           -- point -> 280
       -- 2 // 2nd user   
           -- name -> username2    
           -- point -> 240
       ......

  -- level 3
       -- 1
           -- name -> username1  
           -- point -> 230
       -- 2        
           -- name -> username2   
           -- point -> 200
       ......
```

Comment: but how can I query all users from the same level of dificuly?

Comment: but every time I want to create a new level inside of ranking do I have to create a child inside of it? called Level or something?

Comment: Of course! you can create Unlimited Level inside of ranking if you want! Just do `DatabaseReferance newLevel = mDataRef.child("Level 4");` Now In database path will be create for your new level.

Comment: can you create like a sample so I can run it and try to query them? for instance I have created the user and added it to my firebase database using this : DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid());
                                ref.child("name").setValue(user.getDisplayName());, how can I create this Ranking table and add this user?

Comment: You got my question?

Comment: `DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Level 1").child("1"); ` then `ref.child("name").setValue(name);` | `ref.child("point").setValue(point);`

Comment: This is on start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172352/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-hasib-akter).

Comment: Come to chat hasib

Answer (score 0):

You not need a table only for store ranking if your object USER have the correct properties. Ex:

**CLASS**

```
public class UserData {
    //------PROPERTIES-------
    private String id;
    private String nickname;
    private int points;
    private int level;
    private String email;
}
...
```

**ACTIVITY**

```
private final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
private final DatabaseReference userReference = databaseReference.child("Users");

/** --SAVING USER--
* * THIS METHOD INSERT OBJECT USER IN DATABASE
* **/
private void insertNewUser(String id, String nickname, String email, int points, int level)
{
try {
    UserData userdata = new UserData(id, name, nickname, email, points);
    userReference.child(id).setValue(userdata);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is the better in firestore, you can change this struture and any moment when need... No need begin you project with all strutures completes.
Then for show ranking, you will need only a **OrderBy**

```
rankingRef.orderBy("level").orderBy("points");

/**
* RETRIEVE DATA
* */
    public void loadUsers(final int level)
    {
        final List<UserData> userList = new ArrayList<UserData>();
        if(userList.size() > 0)
        {
            userList.clear();
        }

        //--INITIALIZE--
        userListRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                for(DataSnapshot child: children)
                {
                        UserData user = child.getValue(UserData.class);
                        userList.add(user);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: but what about if I want to query all users from level 1?

Comment: You can chaining .orderby's... Then you need start for we see some code in your question. Will be easy to help after this. Start with store Users. After then the orderBy's. Then if not working, edit your question with news problems

Comment: But I'd like to see how a good structure of db could be, I mean, what I need is user where I store the name, points and other stuff, and then I want like a ranking to find the users from lvl 2 or lvl 4 with its information, you got me?

Comment: It's impossible tell which is better struture for your project without if any code. The best way is start with this code above. This is good for basic situations and you can show ranking. Depends of amount users, size db, and other lot things. Welcome to NoSQL structures. Here nothing need be normalized. NoSql allow desnormalized.

Comment: I know but can you make something like a sample? for instance I have this to insert an user `DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users).child(user.getUid());
                                ref.child("name").setValue(user.getDisplayName());` and  I want an example to insert usert / level in ranking table and then I'll try to query it

Comment: my code above show how .orderBy("level").orderBy("points"); In my sample, level is stored in User Class... And your class ?

Comment: I don't know how many levels will be in game in your case I have to fix it at the start, that's why I want a different tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172353/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-diego-venancio).